# I need help with calculating the intensity of ultrasound

Tags: waves, acoustics, ultrasound

A distance meter, see the picture below, uses ultrasound with a frequency of 50 kHz. The ultrasound is generated by a circular piezoelectric transducer (flat surface that vibrates) with a diameter of 50 mm and which oscillates with an amplitude of 10 micrometers. What is the intensity of the ultrasound 30 m from the distance meter?

You can assume that the ultrasound far from the rangefinder spreads evenly in a cone with a top angle of 20 °, see the figure below. (Ultrasound is propagated at a smaller angle than audible sound because the wavelength is shorter.)

The absorption coefficient is 0.05 m-1 at the frequency 50 kHz in air. (Ultrasound is absorbed much more into air compared to audible sound.)

[image]

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried? Are you having a problem with a concept?

Comment: I have tried intensity formulas but i don't really understand how to use the angle 20 degrees. I used it first to find the height of the cone but I am not sure if that is how I should measure the distance

Comment: Instead of thinking about what formula to use, you might try what ideas to use. You need to find intensity a the wide end of the cone. What is intensity? It is power per unit area? Can you find the power? Area?